# Tensorflow.js is taking too much time to load Coco SSD model with react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow.js

How feasible is it to manage **Tensorflow.js** object detection in the browser.
The fetching and **loading of the model** is taking a **huge amount of time**.

```
(async () => {
  const model = await cocoSSD.load('lite_mobilenet_v2');
  console.log('loaded')
  this.detectFrame(this.video,model);
})()
```

Fetching and loading it on every time is quite expensive on React.js application.
What can we do to solve this?

Comment: In browser it should be fine, it can take a moment to load, but then should be cached by the browser for future page loads, and of course you only have to load model once and then you can call model.detect as many times as desired. However react is not the web browser environment. You may want to reach out to the creator of this post who will know more about the react implementation: https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/02/tensorflowjs-for-react-native-is-here.html

Comment: Yes. It will load faster from the disk cache after the first load. But loading the same in an e-commerce based consumer website is very difficult. the customer might not know or even want to wait till it loads the first time and we can't rely on the customer's cache storage every time. Could we do something better to make it run on browser and also make the customers happy with the time?

Comment: You should use progressive enhancement so only make such features available once you know the model is ready. It should not block the rest of the page load - instead load once the main page has loaded so customer can continue to do other things whilst ML is being activated later or make it click to enable so customer has expectation something will load and provide enhanced functionality.